# Play audio when the source is changed only returns promise pending?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have a function to add an audio tag with an source tag nested, which, when onerror, changes it's audio src to a set one. (yes the audio type also changes)

When i add audio that works, it works and plays.

However when i add music with a path that leads to no where, it initaily gives an error, which triggers the onerror which changes the path. Now when I try to play it returns promise pending.

My goal is to still make the script work even if the sound isn't found.

```
<audio id="path"> 
<source src="path" type="audio/wav" id="path_source" onerror="function () { $('path_source').src='new_path.wav';
$('path_source').type='audio/wav';
">
 </audio>
```

Comment: Please provide your code... so we can reproduce. Read = https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added The code. hope it helps. (Note: The actual html elements are generated within JS but this is the outcome, I am not sure if that has an impact)